# How to append line to empty file using sed, but not echo?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, echo, sudo

I have the following problem: in a script, that must not be executed as root, I have to write a line to a newly created, empty file. This file is in /etc, so I need elevated privilages to write to it.

Creating the file is simple:

```
sudo touch /etc/myfile
```

Now, just using echo to write to the file like so doesn't work...

```
sudo echo "something" > /etc/myfile
```

... because only the first part of the command (echo) is executed with sudo, but not the redirection into the file.

Previously I used something like this...

```
sudo sed -i -e "\$aInsert this" /etc/differntfile
```

...to add to the end of the file, which worked, because the file wasn't empty. But since sed works line based, it doesn't do anything, the file stays completely empty.

Any suggestions? Is there a way to do this with echo somehow? Any special sed expression? Any other tools I could use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `tee`:

```
echo "something" | sudo tee /etc/myfile   # tee -a to append
```

Or redirect to `/dev/null` if you don't want to see the output:

```
echo "something" | sudo tee /etc/myfile > /dev/null
```

Another option is to use `sh -c` to perform the full command under sudo:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "something" > /etc/myfile'
```

---

Regarding doing this with `sed`: I don't think it is possible. Since `sed`  is a stream editor, if there is no stream, there is nothing it can do with it.

Comment: This addresses the problem. Short and straight ++

Comment: Great, this is a lot easier than I expected.

Comment: If you use variables in the command being executed with *sudo sh -c*, you have to use double quotes.

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to upgrade from `sed` (which I also think cannot do this) to `awk` (GNU awk 4.1.0 or higher to be precise), it can be done like this:

```
sudo gawk -i inplace '{ print } ENDFILE { print "something" }' /etc/myfile
```

The alternatives given by the accepted answer are probably easier; I just needed something like this for a use case where I could just use a simple shell command (so no redirection), and the file had to be passed as a single standalone argument (so no `sh -c` which has the target file embedded inside its single argument). Unlike `sed`, `awk` also handles an incomplete last line (which is missing the trailing newline) without adding such.

This uses the *inplace* awk source library; see `man 3am inplace` for details.

Comment: This answer unlike accepted one correctly handles the situation when the last line of the file is not terminated with the new line character. Thanks!

Comment: `man 3am inplace` is worthwhile reading for people who wonder what the heck is going on here. ;)